# PriorityQueue Sorting by Object Property

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, priority-queue

I am trying to insert some objects into a PriorityQueue. I have not implemented any methods that compare objects of the class because there are many ways that the objects could be ordered.

One approach that I saw was to insert the objects into the PriorityQueue as a tuple as (obj.property, obj). The problem with this approach for me is that obj.property is often the same for multiple objects and so I then get a TypeError becaue object is an unorderable type.

What I would like to do is tell the PriorityQueue to sort on obj.property and then I don't care what order objects come out if their property is the same.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your question doesn't really match your name. You ask about the `__cmp__` method in the title, yet your question is really about the behavior of `Queue.PriorityQueue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/queue.html?highlight=priorityqueue):

> The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry
>   is the one returned by sorted(list(entries))[0]). A typical pattern
>   for entries is a tuple in the form: (priority_number, data).

**Update:**

You can create a triple to avoid duplicates, like this:

```
>>> import queue
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, bar):
...         self.bar = bar
...
>>> f1 = Foo('foo')
>>> f2 = Foo('bar')
>>> f3 = Foo('baz')
>>> f4 = Foo('bar')
>>> q = queue.PriorityQueue()
>>> q.put((5,0,f1))
>>> q.put((3,0,f2))
>>> q.put((3,1,f3))
>>> q.put((1,0,f4))
```

Or alternatively (possibly cleaner), implement the [magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#comparisons):

```
>>> import queue
>>> q = queue.PriorityQueue()
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, bar):
...         self.bar = bar
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return self.bar == other.bar
...     def __ne__(self, other):
...         return self.bar != other.bar
...     def __lt__(self, other):
...         return self.bar < other.bar
...     def __gt__(self, other):
...         return self.bar > other.bar
...     def __le__(self, other):
...         return self.bar <= other.bar
...     def __ge__(self, other):
...         return self.bar >= other.bar
...
>>> f1 = Foo('foo')
>>> f2 = Foo('bar')
>>> f3 = Foo('baz')
>>> f4 = Foo('baa')
>>> f5 = Foo('baz')
>>> q.put(f1)
>>> q.put(f2)
>>> q.put(f3)
>>> q.put(f4)
>>> q.put(f5)
```

Comment: Yes. My problem occurs when I have two objects that are of the same priority_number.

Comment: You can create a triple and count duplicates on the second part of the tuple. See my update

Comment: @fdsa duplicates should not be a problem; they will be ordered in a stable-sort manner. It suggests you actually have a different problem.

Comment: I used a global variable to keep track of insertion # so if there was a "tie" the tie would go to the element inserted first. Thanks for your help